# Android layouts not displaying as intended

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create one full screen android activity **programatically** as shown in the image below:[image: how screen should look like]

The two buttons should remain at the bottom of the screen. 
Dummy content will consist of different components (textviews, radio buttons, checkboxes...) and will be populated dynamically.

This is the code I have so far:

```
        //Main Layout
    FrameLayout lLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
    lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //Navigation layout
    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this, null, R.style.ButtonBar);
    LayoutParams bottomLayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    l.setLayoutParams(bottomLayout);
    l.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    l.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66000000"));
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    LayoutParams buttLayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //previous section button
    previousButton = new Button(this);
    previousButton.setLayoutParams(buttLayout);
    previousButton.setText("Previous section");
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    l.addView(previousButton);
    //next section button
    Button nextButton = new Button(this);
    nextButton.setLayoutParams(buttLayout);
    nextButton.setText("Next section");
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    l.addView(nextButton);

    //add components
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("Dummy text");
    tView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lLayout.addView(tView);
    lLayout.addView(l);
    setContentView(lLayout);
```

Here is what the code produces:
[image]

Tthere are several points that do not work as intended:
1. Buttons are at the top and not the bottom.
2. Buttons do not spread out nicely
3. TextView I added as a test is shown behind the buttons. I will have many different widgets on the screen and expect them to be larger than one screen. I would like to have a scroll option but with all those widgets not to be seen behind the two buttons that are supposed to be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Why are you not using the android xml editor to create the Layout?

Comment: Suggest u go with XML

Comment: Due to the nature of the problem XML can not be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following xml is exactly what you would need:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamiclayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigationlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Previous Section" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Next Section" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now programatically inflate **dynamiclayout** and add all your dynamic views into it.

Comment: As I said I can not use XML as I need all this to be developed programatically. I know how to do it through XML, but unfortunatly hardcoding is what I need.

Comment: The dummy content you mentioned is what needs to be added dynamically right? The buttons at the bottom always remain fixed?

Comment: Semi true. Yes dummy content will be generated dynamically but I can not use XML to create buttons as well. I will have dynamic number of the activities that have this screen as their base and in some cases text on buttons will change and sometimes one or the other will not be shown.

Comment: Check the modified xml. That should help. You can change the text on the buttons by inflating the buttons in your code. Also you can hide or show the buttons where you need to do so.

Comment: Eventually I managed to figure out how to do it through XML despite all requirements for dynamic population...

Answer (score 2):

Your root view is a `FrameLayout`, which is intended for only one child View. It is also frequently used to create overlapping Views, as all of a `FrameLayout`'s children will be drawn in the same place on screen.

Replace your `FrameLayout` with a `RelativeLayout`. Make sure you update your `LayoutParams` references to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. You will also need to set the navigation LinearLayout to align with the parent View's bottom like so:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lps = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, true);
```

Though I really would suggest using XML. It will make your life far simpler.

Comment: I figured out how to do it with XML. However, your comment was useful for something else so thank you very much.